# WSL2 removes all my files stored in /mnt/wsl /

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

After shutdown, WSL2 remove any and all files stored in /mnt/wsl for some reason. I haven't been able to find any documentation about this particular case. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, I know, but I just came across this question while researching some other `/mnt/wsl` functionality.

The reason that a shutdown results in files being removed from `/mnt/wsl` is that this mount is using [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs).  This is a filesystem that is created and stored in volatile memory, so it's natural that it will go away on shutdown/restart.

It's apparently created in-memory when the first WSL instance starts, and each additional running WSL instance can connect to it to transfer files between them.

If you'd like to have a non-volatile place to store files between instances, I would just recommend using somewhere on `/mnt/c` or another Windows drive, if possible.  By default, Windows drives do not preserve Linux permissions and ownership, but you can change that (if needed) by mounting (or automounting) the drives with the `metadata` option.  See this [Unix & Linux Stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/631717/432493) answer for more details on that process.

Coming soon (currently in Windows Preview/Insider) is also the ability to create new virtual drives (`.vhdx` files) and mount them.  Those could then be shared between instances as well.

Comment: Interesting. So is /mnt/wsl like a ram drive? or is it still stored on disk and discarded.

Comment: @Brad While it can be implementation dependent (and I'm not sure how WSL implements it), the [tmpfs manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html) says *"contents reside in virtual memory.  Since the files on such filesystems typically reside in RAM, file access is extremely fast."*